# Apache2 won't load css files on Codeigniter, MacOS (Mojave)

Tags: codeigniter, apache2, apache-httpclient-4.x, php-5.6

After using apache from Xampp for a few months, which worked pretty well, I decided to switch to apache2 from the terminal. Because I need using the oracle database, and it seems so confusing if I still use Xampp for the oci8 configuration.

Now, I have just installed apache2, but it seems like it won't load my CSS files on my Codeigniter. I've been struggling with it for hours now and I don't know what else to do.

I just did a clean install from Apache2 and reconfiguration for the oci8 but still didn't work.

I've added some code in my

- /etc/apache2/ httpd.conf
- /usr/local/httpd/httpd.conf

  ```
   AddType text/css .css
   AddType text/javascript .js
  ```

My Project structure that should be fine
[image]

My config base_url:

```
$root = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$root .=str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']),"",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$config['base_url']    = "$root";
```

And how I make a call through my CSS on view:
[image]

Is there anyone that can solve this?
Thanks.

Comment: try: $config['base_url'] = 'http://'.$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"];

Comment: It doesn't work sir @Vickel

Comment: What does `<?php echo base_url(); ?>` gives you?